# ASP.Net Url Rewrite Url Having too many redirects

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a website that has .aspx files sitting inside folders and the current path to the page would be something like /giveaway/giveaway.aspx. I added a url rewrite rule to auto direct the user to the said page when the user enters somedomain.com/giveaway, however i'm getting a error

```
 `This page isn’t working 
 `somedomain.com redirected you too many times.`
```

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here? Below is my rules

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Giveaway" stopProcessing="true">  
        <match url="^giveaway*" />  
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/giveaway" appendQueryString="false" />  
      </rule>  
     <rule name="GiveawayRedirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
       <match url="^giveaway*" /> 
       <action type="Redirect" url="/Giveaway/giveaway.aspx" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
     </rule> 
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=strict" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="No SameSite">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=strict" negate="true" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: this `^giveaway` means basically `/giveaway`. So you will send the redirect in a loop because you send it to `url="/giveaway"`

Comment: And the rule `GiveawayRedirect` will never be reached because the rule is the same as the one above.

Comment: So i just need the top rule?

Comment: No, the top rule is the one that sends it in the loop. You probably just need the bottom one. (as you have discovered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since my path was /giveaway/giveaway it was looping since it used to find the keyword multiple times. I changed my path to /contest/giveaway and now when the user types "/giveaway" it redirects to /contest/giveaway and works properly.

here is my rule

```
<rule name="GiveawayRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^giveaway*" />
           <action type="Redirect" url="/contest/giveaway" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
         </rule>
```